# Numpy - constructing matrix of Jaro (or Levenshtein) distances using numpy.fromfunction

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am doing some text analysis right now and as part of it I need to get a matrix of Jaro distances between all of words in specific list (so pairwise distance matrix) like this one:

```
       │CHEESE CHORES GEESE  GLOVES
───────┼───────────────────────────
CHEESE │    0   0.222  0.177  0.444     
CHORES │0.222       0  0.422  0.333
GEESE  │0.177   0.422      0  0.300
GLOVES │0.444   0.333  0.300      0
```

So, I tried to construct it using `numpy.fromfunction`. Per documentation and examples it passes coordinates to the function, gets its results, constructs the matrix of results.

I tried the below approach:

```
from jellyfish import jaro_distance

def distance(i, j):
    return 1 - jaro_distance(feature_dict[i], feature_dict[j])

feature_dict = 'CHEESE CHORES GEESE GLOVES'.split()
distance_matrix = np.fromfunction(distance, shape=(len(feature_dict),len(feature_dict)))
```

Notice: jaro_distance just accepts 2 strings and returns a float.

And I got a error:

```
File "<pyshell#26>", line 4, in distance
    return 1 - jaro_distance(feature_dict[i], feature_dict[j])
TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

I added `print(i)`, `print(j)` into beginning of the function and I found that instead of real coordinates something odd is passed:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 2.  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 3.  3.  3.  3.]]
[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
 [ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
 [ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
 [ 0.  1.  2.  3.]]
```

Why? The [examples](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html) on numpy site clearly show that just two integers are passed, nothing else.

I tried to exactly reproduce their example using a `lambda` function, but I get exactly same error:

```
distance_matrix = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: 1 - jaro_distance(feature_dict[i], feature_dict[j]), shape=(len(feature_dict),len(feature_dict)))
```

Any help is appreciated - I assume I misunderstood it somehow.

Comment: Could you please turn this into a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? What is `feature_dict`? What is the call signature of `jaro_distance()`?

Comment: It is a complete example, I believe. Feature dict is generated as provided in code in question: feature_dict = 'CHEESE CHORES GEESE GLOVES'.split()

Comment: jaro_distance just get's 2 strings and returns a float. It is not my function, it is provided by jellyfish

Comment: You might look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702105/parameters-to-numpys-fromfunction (first answer) - NumPy's `fromfunction` documentation is somewhat misleading

Comment: Thanks @xnx, it holds the needed information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @xnx I have investigated the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702105/parameters-to-numpys-fromfunction) and found out that fromfunc is not passing coordinates one by one, but actually passess all of indexies at the same time. Meaning that if shape of array would be (2,2) numpy will not perform `f(0,0), f(0,1), f(1,0), f(1,1)`, but rather will perform:

```
f([[0., 0.], [1., 1.]], [[0., 1.], [0., 1.]])
```

But looks like my specific function could vectorized and will produce needed results. So the code to achieve the needed is below:

```
from jellyfish import jaro_distance
import numpy
def distance(i, j):
    return 1 - jaro_distance(feature_dict[i], feature_dict[j])

feature_dict = 'CHEESE CHORES GEESE GLOVES'.split()

funcProxy = np.vectorize(distance)

distance_matrix = np.fromfunction(funcProxy, shape=(len(feature_dict),len(feature_dict)))
```

And it works fine.