# Fast way to calculate kernel matrix, python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

let K(x, z) be (x_transpose*z + p_constant)**2.

I want to compute the n*n matrix K, where K_ij = k(X_i, X_j)

X is a n by d matrix, and X_i is the transpose of the ith row of X.

Does anyone know of a quick way to compute this? I'm using python.

---

Wait a second, is K just XX^T?

Comment: check this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889142/python-numpy-scipy-finding-the-null-space-of-a-matrix

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that's quite what I want here.

Comment: Could you add the actual loopy runnable code?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
def K(x,z, p_constant=1.0):
  return (np.dot(x.T,z)+p_constant)**2
#...
x=np.arange(100).reshape((10,10))
np.fromfunction(np.vectorize(lambda i,j: K(x[i],x[:,j])), x.shape, dtype=x.dtype)
```

I had some trouble with [`np.fromfunction`'s misleading documentation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24900335/3637404)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer on question "How to compute linear kernel matrix" is

```
np.dot(X , np.transpose(X).
```