# How to make numpy array based on function called for each element?

Tags: python, numpy

The [numpy.fromfunction](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html) makes a single call to the function with arguments as arrays, as described in e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18709458/3989931). So to use numpy.fromfunction it is required that the function takes array arguments and return an array also.

How to make numpy array based on function called for each element, where the function returns a scalar for the element, as for example using the `max` function like below ?

```
z = numpy.fromfunction(max, (2, 2), dtype=int)
```

Which would then return:

```
[[0 1]
 [1 1]]
```

Comment: Not sure I get your question: z will be scalar so why should it be an array?

Comment: Why don't you just use `np.max` or if you want to use another function what is that exactly? Is there no equivalent for that in numpy?

Comment: @Kasramvd: Max was just an example function; the question is still thought to be a matter for a general solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) for that

```
vmax = numpy.vectorize(max)
z = numpy.fromfunction(vmax, (2, 2), dtype=int)
```

Please note this sentence from the docs though:

> The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

By its very nature `numpy.vectorize` will be slow. In this example `numpy.maximum` will be much faster:

```
z = numpy.fromfunction(numpy.maximum, (2, 2), dtype=int)
```

Comment: For a general solution that is fine.  My engineering performance will be higher when writing like that, and if the code then executes too slowly I will optimize later :-)

Comment: I understand. I am just arguing that you should try and use `numpy` functions wherever possible.