# Why am I getting an IndexError in this ndarray creation using a lambda expression Python

Tags: python, numpy, lambda

The code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    assert type(x) is np.ndarray
    return np.fromfunction(lambda i: np.sum(x[:i + 1]), (x.size,))


print(f(np.array((1, 2, 3))))

IndexError: failed to coerce slice entry of type numpy.ndarray to integer
```

I would expect the outcome to be [1, 1 + 2, 1 + 2 + 3] = [1, 3, 6]. If I change the return line of f to be:

```
return np.fromfunction(lambda i: np.sum(x[:int(i) + 1]), (x.size,))
```

I get:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I am simply mapping i to a constant and i should take the values 0, ..., x.size - 1 so I don't see whats wrong here.

Comment: Numpy does have a [cumulative sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.cumsum.html)

Comment: Yes but its the concept behind it. I want to do it with a different function, not the sum but it still happens. Why is this not equivalent to the cumulative sum?

Comment: `fromfunction()` calls your lambda function *once*, with argument `np.arange(x.size)`.  That is, `i` will be an array, not a scalar.

Comment: ah thank you!, I thought it repeatedly applied it to the indices. I wrote one like this and it worked but I forgot about vectorised operations.

Comment: If you want to use a different function, consider `np.frompyfunc(...).accumulate`

Comment: So what you want is `np.array([np.sum(x[:i+1]) for i in range(len(x))])`

Comment: For source code  and complaints about its documentation see https://stackoverflow.com/q/18702105.