# numpy's fromfunction accessing arrays in the input function

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a numpy matrix with each matrix element as output element of a function, using numpy's `fromfunction`. Below is my code and it fails with an error message `IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type`. I read some resources on Stackoverflow which said that the documentation is misleading ([Parameters to numpy's fromfunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702105/parameters-to-numpys-fromfunction)) and it sometimes doesn't work as expected. After reading these threads, I suspect that the problem is that I access two arrays, `q_x` and `rs` in the input function. Any idea on how to get rid of the error?

```
import numpy as np
q_x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
rs = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8])

def ift_weight(i,j):
    qr = q_x[i]*rs[j]
    return qr*np.sin(qr)

print(np.fromfunction(ift_weight, (5,5)))
```

Remarks: There are of course some workarounds such as creating an empty matrix and then iterate each element. I am curious whether numpy's `fromfunction` can achieve such task more elegantly.

Edit: np.vectorize perfectly solved the problem. I might have made some typo so that my previous trial with np.vectorize fails. This question is a duplicate of  [Parameters to numpy's fromfunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702105/parameters-to-numpys-fromfunction)

Comment: Read the `[source]`.  This is a simple function, nearly useless.  It creates `indices` and passes them (whole) to your function.  It's docs are misleading because people **want** it to do something else.  It is **not** a 'vectorizing' magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link that you attached already addressed the problem perfectly. Could you elaborate on the case that it doesn't work?

So the problem here is that `np.fromfunction` is handing over the whole meshgrid instead of a single index.

```
(Pdb) p i
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [4., 4., 4., 4., 4.]])
(Pdb) p j
array([[0., 1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [0., 1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [0., 1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [0., 1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [0., 1., 2., 3., 4.]])
```

Applying the `np.vectorize` and specifying `dtype=int` for indexing solves the problem.

```
import numpy as np
q_x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
rs = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8])


def ift_weight(i, j):
    qr = q_x[i]*rs[j]
    return qr*np.sin(qr)


f = np.vectorize(ift_weight)

print(np.fromfunction(f, (5, 5), dtype=int))
```

Comment: You are right. Thanks. I thought I had done something the exact same as yours here, but I also got an error message. I have deleted my previous code and I can't reproduce the error again. Anyway, thanks!